# Inconsistent Rounding Mode When Passing Python Float to C function

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a quesiton regarding the rounding mode in C++. I would like to change the rounding mode to see if we can get the upper- and lowerbound of a given variable.

By running some toy examples with following code, I can get some super strange observations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cfenv>
#include <cmath>
void test_c(const bool rounding_up, const float x) 
{   
    #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
    float y = 1e-6;
    if (rounding_up){
        std::fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
        std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << "x_up_python   " << x << "\n";
        std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << "y_up_c++   " << y << "\n";
    }
    else{
        std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
        std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << "x_down_python " << x << "\n";
        std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << "y_down_c++ " << y << "\n";
    }
}
extern "C" {
    void test(const bool rounding_up, const float x){
        test_c(rounding_up, x);
        }
}
```

```
import os
import numpy as np
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

import ctypes
from ctypes import cdll
from ctypes import *

os.system('g++ -c -fPIC post_processing.cpp -o post_processing.o')
os.system('g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,lib_rounding.so -o lib_rounding.so post_processing.o')
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib_rounding.so')

def test(x, rounding_up=True):
    lib.test.restype = None
    lib.test.argtypes = [ctypes.c_bool, ctypes.c_float]
    lib.test(rounding_up, x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 1e-6
    test(x, True)
    test(x, False)
```

Firstly, let's have a look at `y`. If the rounding mode is set to be `FE_UPWARD`, the resulted value is `9.999999975e-07`. In comparison, if the rounding mode is set to be `FE_DOWNWARD`, the resulted value is `9.999999974e-07`.

Secondly, if I define `x=1e-6` in a `python` script, and then use `ctype` to pass `x` to this C function. The results are reversed, namely `FE_UPWARD` returns `9.999999975e-07` and `FE_DOWNWARD` returns `1.000000111e-06`.

So, I have 2 questions in total:

1. For the first observation, why both of them are smaller than `1e-6`?
2. As for the second observation, why is the relation of these 2 values reversed?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please show also the Python code used to call the function.

Comment: Hi, I just added the Python code and the left C++ code to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question 1e-6 in floating point binary is a repeating fraction so precision is lost.  Single-precision floating point reserves 23 bits for mantissa and the rest are dropped and the least significant bit is rounded, so the number can appear smaller or larger when written out to more precision.  23 bits translates to about 7 digits of decimal precision.

For the second question, changing the rounding mode is sticky and isn't restored after calling your C++ function.  It affects Python's conversions of Python float to C float through ctypes as well.  Change the code to the following to save and restore the original mode and you'll get consistency:

```
    float y = 1e-6;

    auto org = std::fegetround();  // Save original mode

    if (rounding_up){
        std::fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
        std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << "x_up_python   " << x << "\n";
        std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << "y_up_c++   " << y << "\n";
    }
    else{
        std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
        std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << "x_down_python " << x << "\n";
        std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << "y_down_c++ " << y << "\n";
    }

    std::fesetround(org);  // Restore original mode
```

```
x_up_python   9.999999975e-07
y_up_c++   9.999999975e-07
x_down_python 9.999999974e-07
y_down_c++ 9.999999974e-07
```

The IEEE hex dump of the `x` float in a debugger showed `0x358637BD` in one mode and `0x358637BE` in the other so the mantissa (last 23 bits) was rounding differently during the Python float (internally in CPython as C double) to C float conversion.  The `y` float always read `0x358637BD`.