# how set and retain the the x87 floating point precision mode

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, ctypes, x87

Q1: I have following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fpu_control.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    fpu_control_t fpu_oldcw, fpu_cw = 0x0000007f;
    
    //get old control word
  
    _FPU_GETCW(fpu_oldcw);
    printf("Current control word is: 0x%.8x\n", fpu_oldcw);    
    
    //set the mode    
    _FPU_SETCW(fpu_cw);

    //check the changed mode
    _FPU_GETCW(fpu_oldcw);
    printf("Modified control word is: 0x%.8x\n", fpu_oldcw);
```

The output is as expected:

```
Current control word is: 0x0000037f
Modified control word is: 0x0000007f
```

This correctly sets the new floating point precision mode. However once the executable is finished, if I reread the control word from another c program then the mode is "0x0000037f". This means previous changed value "0x0000007f" is not retained. So basically how do we retain the new mode? means once we change it, then mode stays updated until we manually change it back to original or whatever.

Q2: Is there any way i can change and retain the mode directly from python? My current thoughts are if i have getter/setter c programs then I can call that code like below in python:

```
from subprocess import call

call(["./set_precision"])
or 
call(["./get_precision"])
```

This will only work if the updated mode is retained between two calls to c executable (which is generated by gcc compiler). Another option I was thinking using ctypes like below

```
libm = ctypes.CDLL("libm.so.6", ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
old_rmode = libm.fegetround()
print( "old_rmode: ", hex(old_rmode) )
```

However in this case i found only rounding mode but nothing for precision.

Could you please advise what is the best way to set and retain the precision mode on x87 hardware? Thank you.

Comment: Separate processes, separate thread contexts.  It isn't a global for all processes in the system.  Would you want some process messing with the results of another?

Comment: Thank you Mark for the comments. Definitely not. I don't want to mess the processing. It is just lack of knowledge on my part. what i want to do in python is 1) change the mode from 0x0000037f to 0x0000007f 2) do my processing/caluations 3) change the mode back from 0x0000007f to default mode 0x0000037f?

Comment: Make a pair of C DLL functions the change the mode.  Use `ctypes` module to call the functions from the python process, not by calling a subprocess.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64920804/235698

Comment: Is [_controlfp](http://systemmanager.ru/svcsunix.en/extfile/sir/_controlfp.htm) what you are looking for?

Comment: Many thanks, Mark. I'll look into these.